# Combine rows where variables are the same using python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that has rows like this

```
   Same1  Same2  Diff3  Encoded1  Encoded2  Encoded3
0     33     22    150         0         0         0
1     33     22    300         1         0         1
```

What I want to achieve is to combine all rows where the 'Same1' and 'Same2' variables are the same, by adding up the other variables.

```
   Same1  Same2  Diff3  Encoded1  Encoded2  Encoded3
0     33     22    450         1         0         1
```

What would be the cleanest way to achieve this using pandas?

Executable python code:
https://trinket.io/python3/1da371fd04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```py
out = df.groupby(['Same1', 'Same2']).agg(sum).reset_index()
```

```
print(out)

   Same1  Same2  Diff3  Encoded1  Encoded2  Encoded3
0     33     22    450         1         0         1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to get the expected result :

```py
df.groupby(['Same1', 'Same2'], as_index=False).sum()
```

Output :

```
    Same1   Same2   Diff3   Encoded1    Encoded2    Encoded3
0   33      22      450     1           0           1
```